# implement tint color and translucent toolbar properties android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

THe tint color and translucent properties are IOS centric. I am trying to implement these properties for the android platform. I have scoured the web for a while and I am not getting anywhere. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with "tint color and translucent properties", but it might be worth taking a look at [ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html).

[Here](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/QuickActionActivity.java) is an example of use of LightingColorFilter in GreenDroid. Scroll down to MyQuickAction class and use of BLACK_CF.